# How to reverse an int but grouped by 2 bit in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Like this:

```
input:  10010011
(10->01->00->11)

output: 11000110
(11->00->01->10)


input:  11010001
(11->01->00->01)

output: 01000111
(01->00->01->11)
```

Anyone has any ideas about that?

Comment: An inefficient way would be to chop it up into pairs, then reverse the list of pairs.

Comment: What have you tried?  Basically you're working with a char array, not 'bits', I assume?

Comment: @Luchian It's the bit string read from right to left, in groups of two bits.

Comment: @Vernon It's an array consist of four kinds of char(DNA): `A` `T` `C` `G`

Comment: So you want the code for a ribosome? :-)

Comment: @lserni yes, the sequence motif of positive and negative strand :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fewer operations than [lserni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428679/lserni)'s [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12205195/1011995):

```
uint32_t reverseByTwo(uint32_t value) {
    value = ((value & 0x03030303) << 2) | ((value >> 2) & 0x03030303); // swap adjacent pairs
    value = ((value & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4) | ((value >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F); // swap nibbles
    value = ((value & 0x00FF00FF) << 8) | ((value >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF); // swap bytes
    value = ((value & 0x0000FFFF) << 16) | ((value >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF);
    return value;
}
```

For 64-bit values just add another swap for the 32-bit halves, for smaller types, just leave out the last few swaps.

Answer (score 3):

Weird request. I'd do it like this:

```
uint32_t reverseByTwo(uint32_t value)
{
    int i;
    uint32_t new_value = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        new_value <<= 2;            
        new_value |= (value & 0x3);
        value >>= 2;
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

At each iteration, the two LSB of value are placed in the two LSB of new_value, which is shifted to the left.

For an eight-bit value,

```
uint8_t reverseByTwo(uint8_t value)
{
    int i;
    uint32_t new_value = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        new_value <<= 2;            
        new_value |= (value & 0x3);
        value >>= 2;
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

if performances are at a premium, you can manually unroll the loop (GCC should do this by itself, but sometimes doesn't bother) and declare the function as `inline`.

```
    new_value = 0;
    // new_value <<= 2; // First time not necessary
    new_value |= (value & 0x3);
    value >>= 2;
    new_value <<= 2;            
    new_value |= (value & 0x3);
    value >>= 2;
    new_value <<= 2;            
    new_value |= (value & 0x3);
    value >>= 2;
    new_value <<= 2;            
    new_value |= (value & 0x3);
    // value >>= 2; 
    return new_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest possible way to transform the bits in a single byte (char) into another single byte is to build yourself an array:

```
unsigned char rev[256];
rev[0]   = 0;     /* 00000000 -> 00000000 */
...
rev[147] = 198;   /* 10010011 -> 11000110 */
...
rev[198] = 147;   /* 11000110 -> 10010011 */
...
rev[255] = 255;   /* 11111111 -> 11111111 */
```

To convert a number x to its bit-reversed form, just write `rev[x]`.  If you have multiple bytes to convert, such as in a 4-byte `int`, just look up the 4 bytes in the `rev` table.

You'll need to convert binary to another base (here, I use decimal) when writing this code, because C doesn't have binary constants (which would be ten times more useful than octal constants).

You could also put the values into the initializer, but you'll have to count positions to make sure everything is in the right place.  (Maybe write a little program to do it!)

```
unsigned char rev[256] = {0, ..., 198, ..., 147, ..., 255};
```

Fill in the `...` with all the other numbers in the right places.

Comment: "Maybe write a little program to do it!" - yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = (($x & 0x33333333) << 2) | (($x & 0xCCCCCCCC) >> 2);
$x = (($x & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4) | (($x & 0xFOFOFOFO) >> 4);
$x = (($x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8) | (($x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8);
$x = (($x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16) | (($x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
```

To give credit where due, this algorithm came from "Hacker's Delight" by Henry S. Warren, Jr. The only difference is that the algorithm in the book didn't reverse by pairs; it just reversed the bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <limits.h>

#define INT_BITS  (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)

unsigned reverse_bits(unsigned x) {
#define PAIR(i)       ((((x) >> (i*2)) & 3) << (INT_BITS - (i+1)*2))
    unsigned result = 0;
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < INT_BITS/2; i++) {
        result |= PAIR(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Though this will do it for an unsigned int, whereas you might want to replace `int` and `unsigned` there with `char` and `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fastest possible:

```
output =
  ((input & 0xc0) >> 6) |
  ((input & 0x30) >> 2) |
  ((input & 0xc) << 2) |
  ((input & 0x3) << 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bits (ab cd ef gh) and want (gh ef cd ab)
If you multiply by 0x101 and store in 16 bit int, you get (ab cd ef gh ab cd ef gh).
Then you have your bit pattern in that number in two group of four bits:

- (00 00 **ef** 00 **ab** 00 00 00),
- (00 00 00 **gh** 00 **cd** 00 00)

So you just have to shift and mask appropriately

```
unsigned char swap_bit_pairs(unsigned char b)
{
    unsigned int a = 0x101*b;
    return ((a >> 6) & 0x33) | ((a >> 2) & 0xCC);
}
```

So it's possible in 6 operations

**EDIT:** oups! I wrote 0x66 instead of 0xCC